# Retrieving response text from curl in cpp

Tags: c++, curl, httpresponse

we need to receive response string from curl in CPP ,I tried following options but nothing worked.js uses xhr.responseText for this.I need to do in cpp.

```
 static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    const char* sp = static_cast<const char*>(contents);
    readBuffer.append(sp, realsize);
    return realsize;
 }

CURLcode res;
char* http_error= new char[100];

readBuffer.clear();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
cout <<  "Curl response msg CURLOPT_WRITEDATA: "<<curl_easy_strerror(code)<< " respose :"<<readBuffer;


res=curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code) ;
cout <<  "Curl response msg: "<< curl_easy_strerror(res);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use high-level library https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr

Comment: there is no direct method for this like retrieving the http status code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `WriteCallback` function to this:

```
size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* userp) {
    userp->append((char*) contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

Remember, you are passing in `&readBuffer` as the `CURL_WRITEDATA` option. This shows up as the fourth parameter in the `WriteCallback`. Since the type of `&readBuffer` is `std::string*`, you can use that as the signature in your callback.

Additionally, since it's a `std::string*` and not a `std::string`, you have to access `append` through the pointer, hence the `->` instead of `.`. After `curl_easy_perform`, `readBuffer` should hold the response from the curl request.

To get the response code, you can grab that after making the request:

```
long http_code;
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying..inside userp->append((char*) ptr, size * nmemb); ptr is sp(contents)?

Comment: Oops, mistyped it. I'll correct it. You're right, it's supposed to be contents.